# SQL show static values for a column that never changes but update other columns as needed

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am wondering what the best way to have a static column in sql that wouldnt show up because of a WHERE clause. In my code below I have a Designer. I would like to have all of the designers show up even if they do not meet the WHERE condition, but have the value associated with the condition of the WHERE.

```
SELECT first_assigned_to AS Designer, 
           Count(DISTINCT quote_email) AS totalLeads 
    FROM   quotes_new_assigned 
    WHERE  date_first_assigned_to >= YEAR(CURDATE())
    GROUP  BY designer
```

> This is what the SELECT will give us at the end of the year

```
adam   38
bob    1711
brenda 823
chris  7
dave   426
diane  52
```

> This is what I would like it to give (values dont matter, just notice how the ones that do not have any quotes assigned to them still show up)

```
adam   0
bob    0
brenda 3
chris  1
dave   0
diane  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using a CASE WHEN inside the COUNT.

```
SELECT first_assigned_to AS Designer, 
Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN date_first_assigned_to >= YEAR(CURDATE()) THEN quote_email END) AS totalLeads 
FROM  quotes_new_assigned  
GROUP BY first_assigned_to;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left join on the subquery and the distinct for your designer

```
  SELECT distinct a.first_assigned_to AS Designer, ifnull(t.totalLeads,0)
  FROM   quotes_new_assigned as a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT first_assigned_to AS Designer, 
             Count(DISTINCT quote_email) AS t.totalLeads 
      FROM   quotes_new_assigned 
      WHERE  date_first_assigned_to >= YEAR(CURDATE())
      GROUP  BY designer 
  ) t on a.designer = t.designer 
  WHERE  a.date_first_assigned_to >= YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union with a distinct query on a list of the remaining designers:

```
SELECT first_assigned_to AS Designer, Count(DISTINCT quote_email) AS totalLeads 
WHERE  date_first_assigned_to >= YEAR(CURDATE())    
GROUP  BY designer 
UNION   
SELECT Distinct first_assigned_to AS Designer,  0 AS totalLeads 
WHERE  date_first_assigned_to < YEAR(CURDATE()
```